# Android Paginated Map Bad Performance

Tags: java, android, performance, pagination, hashmap

We are coming from here:
    [Java Paginated List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36424856/java-paginated-list)

In this old post I needed to Paginate a `List` of different `Object`. Finally I solved it creating a `Map`, like this:

```
private Map<Integer, List<List<MyObject>>> paginateRequest(List<List<MyObject>> requestLists, double pageSize) {
Map<Integer, List<List<MyObject>>> result = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, List<List<MyObject>>>();
int totalElements = 0;

//We calculate the total of the elements contained in the requestLists.
for(List<MyObject> subList : requestLists) {
    if(subList != null) {
        totalElements += subList.size();
    }
}

//We round it up. The result Map will contain x pages with {pageSize} elements each one. For example, if the total amount of request is 101,
//our Map will have 2 pages (100 elements + 1 element)
int totalRequests = (int)Math.ceil(totalElements / pageSize);

//We iterate over each page
for(int i=0; i<totalRequests; i++) {
    List<List<MyObject>> entry = new LinkedList<List<MyObject>>();

    int freeElements = (int)pageSize;

    for(List<MyObject> list : requestLists) {
        List<MyObject> subList = new LinkedList<MyObject>();
        if(freeElements > 0) {
            if(list.size() > freeElements) {
                subList.addAll(list.subList(0, freeElements));
            }else {
                subList.addAll(list);
            }
            //We update the left free elements
            freeElements -= subList.size();
        }
        entry.add(subList);
        list.removeAll(subList);

    }
    //We add a new page to the result Map
    result.put(i, entry);
}

return result;
}
```

Now I realised that when the `totalRequests` contains a hight value (more than 100 elements) this piece of code runs very slow on Android 4 devices. It takes around 7-8 seconds on Android >= 5, but more than 30-40 seconds on Android 4.4 for example (I've tested it on the Android Emulator).

I can't understand what's the problem with the Android version, it has absolutely nothing to do with Android, it is just Java operations.

I also don't know how I could improve it, I know there are a lot of insertion operations and looping over a hight amount of elements is expensive but I don't see another way to implement it more efficiently.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.